# Unable to restart IIS Website from Other Server

Tags: iis, jenkins

We are using Jenkins as our Continous Integration Server. One of our project requires restarting IIS website on other Server. We can use 
"cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd stop site /site.name:xyz" 
appcmd start site /site.name:xyz"  to restart xyz site from the same server.

We are unable to CD to network path using CD. I tried with Powershell, and I can cd to network location. I have tried Stop-Site, which doesn't works. 
I want powershell script or batch file, which can help me to restart IIS website on other server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart it with `iisreset`.
Just run command prompt like admin and run it:

> iisreset

If you want know other on iisreset see here [How to reset IIS with the IIS Reset command](https://gearhost.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200341925-How-to-reset-IIS-with-the-IIS-Reset-command)

Comment: I want to use iisreset on other machine. This can work only on same server. I want to use iisreset from server 1 to server 2

Comment: You can use iisreset with other machine too. Only use iisreset <servername>, change <servername> with another server.

Comment: I will implement this command on Jenkins and would keep you updated.

Comment: IIS Reset is working that way, but it will be great, if I can only stop 1 site on other server.

Comment: does not this command require a username and password? `invoke-command -computername $serverName {cd C:\Windows\System32\; ./cmd.exe /c "iisreset /noforce /RESTART" }` I have this script and is working on same machine but on remote.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it with powershell coding and functions
CI_IIS_Reset.exe STARTWEBSITE servername sitename username password